# How do I alias a column name in Propel query for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, symfony, propel

I need to prevent inserting dupes into the object fields table. Users can enter inputs for this field in UI with/without spaces b/w the words and also upper/lower case of the field name, for example:

```
1. test field
2. TestField
3. TEST FIELD
```

Any combination of above. I should prevent inserting dupe values by scrubbing the white spaces b/w words.  The check is only for checking the existing value before insert/update.  But we store the actual input given by the user.

I have to write a propel query in Symfony which is equivalent of below Oracle select query that I run to check for the same "field name" existence.

```
`SELECT lower(REPLACE(field_name, ' ', '')), 
       field_id 
 from object_fields 
 where field_name=lower('testfield');`
```

SYmfony/Propel Query I have tried:

```
$fieldName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($fieldName));
    $selectColumn = "lower(REPLACE( ObjFieldsPeer::FIELD_NAME,' ', ''))";
    ObjFieldsQuery::create( )
        ->withColumn($selectColumn)
        ->filterByFieldName( $fieldName )
        ->findOne( );
```

It gives me the following Oracle SQL Query:

```
select OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_ID, 
       lower(REPLACE(OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_NAME, ' ', ''))  
              AS lowerREPLACEOBJECT_FIELDSFIELD_NAME, ' ', ''
FROM  OBJECT_FIELDS  
WHERE OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_NAME='testfield';
```

and I get Oracle error as " ORA-00972: identifier is too long"

Anyone has any idea how to write the same query in Propel/Symfony with alias name for the column ?

Thanks 
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think this should work:

```
$fieldName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($fieldName));
    $selectColumn = "lower(REPLACE( ObjFieldsPeer::FIELD_NAME,' ', ''))";
    ObjFieldsQuery::create( )
        ->withColumn($selectColumn, 'your_alias')
        ->filterByFieldName( $fieldName )
        ->findOne( );
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. It worked for one use case. Also, may I know how do I use replace function in my where clause ?
query will be something like.. 

select OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_ID, 
       lower(REPLACE(OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_NAME, ' ', ''))  
              AS lowerREPLACEOBJECT_FIELDSFIELD_NAME, ' ', ''
FROM  OBJECT_FIELDS  
WHERE OBJECT_FIELDS.FIELD_NAME='testfield';

Comment: I'm out of my depth now, haven't looked at Propel for a while - try asking a new question.